# HTTPS is working but HTTP is not working - Apache2

Tags: php, apache, virtualhost

I have configured my virtual host for both HTTP & HTTPS, but my site is accessable on HTTPS, but not on HTTP. what could be the possible issue here?

Here is my configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>

        ServerName mysite.com
        ServerAlias www.mysite.com

        DocumentRoot /var/www/html


        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/certificates/certificate.cer
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/certificates/key.pkey
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/certificates/mysite.com-2017.txt
        SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
</VirtualHost>
```

What could be the possible issue here?

Comment: Check apache config for any warnings:  `apachectl -t`.  Use `netstat -tln` to confirm something is listening on ports 80 & 443. Can you provide the error message when attempting to access port 80?

Comment: have you opened inbound access to port 80 on server .?

Comment: I am getting no errors

Comment: I havn't done anything specific for inbounding port 80, do I have to?

Comment: Can you access port 80 locally with `curl` from your server? Is there a firewall locally on the box or with your hosting provider?